# Kotlin Multiplatform - Get file list from directory

Tags: android, kotlin-multiplatform

We include an assets folder in our KMM shared/commonMain project.
This asset folder basically contains a lot of JSON files, structured in different sub-folders.

In build.gradle, the assets folder is added as android resource, so its included in the root of the build AAR.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion(29)
    sourceSets["main"].resources.srcDirs("src/commonMain/assets")
    ...
```

In the shared module, the files are reads on demand in commonAndroid with

```
val file = this::class.java.classLoader!!.getResource(folder1/file1.json)
```

This works perfectly fine.

Now to the issue, reading a folder:

```
val folder= this::class.java.classLoader!!.getResource(folder1)
```

This works when code is executed via unit tests, then it returns the folder.
Once the AAR is build and included in an android app, this line always returns null.

Keep in mind, the files are properly added to the AAR, and they can be read when specifying the path to the file. Its just not working with the folder path only.

Is there any way to get all files from a directory in the AAR module, from within the KMM project?

The iOS solution is working, so its really just about android.

**EDIT 1:**
To clarify, the goal is not to provide access to the folder/files to an external user, it is to use the files within the KMM common module itself.

I am looking for any way to work with files and folders that also works once the project is distributed as AAR and used as third party library.

**EDIT 2:**
It seems like there currently is no solution to access folders in JARS that are within AARs.

So we switched to a workaround, where we generate an index file of all files within the folder at build time, and use this information at runtime to get all files from specific folders, using `this::class.java.classLoader!!.getResource(path)` (as getResource works for files, just not for folders)

Comment: Once you had a 'folder' how would you continue to make a listing of files and subfolders?

Comment: Get the absolute path with `val absoluteFolderPath = folder.path` and continue to work with `File(folderPathAbsolute).listFiles` etc.  I thought there would for sure be a KMM feature for shared resources, but could not find anything.

Comment: You cannot use the File class for assets. That can never work. But you said it worked with unit tests in this way? Impossible.

Comment: Ok, I think the foldername 'assets' is missleading. It is just a random folder within the library, which contains files that should be read within the library. It has nothing todo with outside-of-library android assets.

Comment: I realise this message comes incredibly late and is not overly relevant, but do you have a full solution to this issue? I have file checking/loading on Android working but struggling on the iOS side...

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a problem with proguard.

Move your json folders from assets folder to raw folder and changed the keep.xml file.

keep.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:keep="@drawable/*,@raw/*"/>
```

reference: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code#keep-resources

Comment: The library is an internal library, so it does not use proguard. When inspecting the resulting AAR, all folders and files are included as expected.